# Ondrop event in HTML5

Tags: html

`ondrop` event is working in chrome correctly. But it is not working in the Safari web browser. I am using Safari 5.1.2. I test it with an example

**Web link**: http://www.pageresource.com/html5/examples/draganddrop.html

What can I do for making it workable in Safari?

Comment: Not working *how*? Is there an error? Does it do something unusual?

Comment: Yes there is an error _ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dragEnd_. I cleared that error, but not working .

Answer (score 0):

According to W3Schools, it's not supported in Safara 5.1.2:

"Note: Drag and drop does not work in Safari 5.1.2."

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp